# Can I set a doctype at the server level?

Tags: apache, doctype, internet-explorer-10

My company is moving from win7 to win8 soon and I've been tasked with updating our applications to work in IE10. Currently we run them in IE8.

The problem is that none of them have doctypes declared so IE8 defaults to rendering them in IE5 mode. Well with IE10 the default rendering mode has changed so to keep rendering them properly I need to either declare a doctype in all our pages(which would be cumbersome) or find a global way to do this.

So my question is is there a way to tell my server(Apache 2.2) to insert a doctype into my pages that don't have one?

thanks

Comment: If you've always relied in quirks mode rendering, just adding a DOCTYPE will make things worse, won't it?

Comment: I've tested a couple of the applications. if I set the type to 'ie5quirks' then it renders the way I'm expecting it to. I'd love to go back and rewrite the programs to work for IE10 but there just isn't the man power to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the doctype server-side, but you can set the X-UA-Compatible header server-side. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanuk/archive/2008/08/28/apache-httpd-configuration-for-ie7-standard-mode-rendering-in-ie8.aspx for details on how to do that.

The following page describes how this works in IE10: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920756(v=vs.85).aspx